# Azure WebJobs Status

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-triggered

I am new to Azure portal.
I have a client application on .net which is currently deployed on Azure. Our project does sends emails to customers through sendgrid API. For emails, some customers complain they see the status as In pending and not delivered.

I checked webjobs in Azure portal for the logs and I am wondering since that email which is not delivered was from 3 march 2022. Is there a way that we can filter the webjobs accprding to the time we want as there are a lot.

Comment: Can you please elaborate "I am wondering since that email which is not delivered was from 3 march 2022. Is there a way that we can filter the webjobs"

Comment: Hi Sure. What I meant is we have webjobs to check the status of emails sent to customers if that was a success or not.. There are like 2000 emails sent daily so I am not able to scroll this much backward till 3rd mach to check if email was delivered to specific customer that day. Can we filter webjobs with particular time criteria?

FUNCTION STATUS STATUS DETAIL
Functions.ProcessQueueMessage ({"ESlipId":671417}, ) Success 47 seconds ago (1 s running time)

Comment: Well, there is no easy way to check the success and failure rate from the console output of webjob. I am assuming that you webjob runs on schedule so you should have multiple logs. One for each run. So you need to look for the log for the specific date. And may be by scrolling through that you can see how many was sent and how many failed. But then again it is a tedious job. You should ask your dev to write a better reporting option, for example - write the required data in a azure storage table.

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain more on this. what can be suggested to get the details